# Google API V3: computeOffset function

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I would like to know the units of measurement for the ComputeOffset function in the geometry library in Google Maps API V3.

The documentation says

> computeOffset(from:LatLng, distance:number, heading:number,
> radius?:number)

I can see that heading is in degrees. In what units is the distance. What is the use of the optional radius?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distance is in meters.

radius is defined in the first method listed.

> The radius defaults to the Earth's radius in meters

If you change the radius to be in other units (like miles), the answer will be in those units.